# Impulse response's flip in convolution

Tags: signal-processing, convolution

During convolution on a signal, why is impulse response's flip needed during the process?

Comment: this might be better asked on http://dsp.stackexchange.com/!

Comment: Better suited for dsp.stackexchange.com. But if you don't flip one of the signals, you end up calculating a correlation. You can prove to yourself that you need the flip by convolving, say, the signal [1,1,1] with the impulse response [3,2,1]. If you don't flip, the output doesn't look like the intuitively expected result.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the DSP part of StackExchange..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you does not have to flip one of the signals, but in that case it's  called the cross-correlation, where not only the reverse is needed, but also the complex conjugate of a signal is required. See [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2654/what-is-the-difference-between-convolution-and-cross-correlation/) and answers.